# Jobtracker and tasktracker not showing

Tags: hadoop

I am using hadoop 2.7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, when I run hadoop 
and use jps, the following processes are shown:

```
Resourcemanager
Namenode
Datanode
Jps
SecondaryNameNode
NodeManager
```

Here job tracker and tasktracker are not shown.  What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are running **Hadoop 2.7.1**(which is based on MRv2 and NOT MRv1) that's why you will only see "Resourcemanager Namenode Datanode SecondaryNameNode NodeManager" and NOT "job tracker and tasktracker". "job tracker and tasktracker" are MRv1's concept and NOT MRv2.

Comment: Dear Ashu, don't just answer questions, but also edit the questions so they're more easily read by the next user that reads the same question.  Thank you!  **:-)**

Comment: This question was very clear to me at least as it's from my filed of work and the answer i provided is also clear.

Comment: This website is not about you, nor the user you're helping, but about the entire community of Ubuntu users that find questions and answers, so the clearer the question (it was not) and the clearer the answer (it was and is), the better the entire Ubuntu community moves forward!  **;-)**